# How can I have a templated argument but with one overload each for l-value and r-value?

Tags: c++

I want functions that are templated to take any argument, but I want to distinguish whether it's an l-value or an r-value:

```
class PointerBase
{public:

    PointerBase& operator=(const PointerBase&); // TO PREVENT COMPILER-GENERATED
    PointerBase& operator=(PointerBase&&); // TO PREVENT COMPILER-GENERATED


    template <typename AnyDerivedType>
    void operator=(const AnyDerivedType& ptr)
    {
        /* COPY */
    }
    template <typename AnyDerivedType>
    void operator=(AnyDerivedType&& ptr)
    {

        /* MOVE */
    }



};


class PointerDerived
{public:
    
};

int main()
{
    PointerBase b;
    PointerDerived d;

    b = d; /* CALLS THE && FUNCTION*/
    b = std::move(d); // CALLS THE SAME && FUNCTION
}
```

I thought a way to do it would be:

```
template <typename AnyDerivedType>
    void assign(AnyDerivedType& rhs)
    {

    }
    template <typename AnyDerivedType>
    void move(AnyDerivedType&& rhs)
    {

    }

    template <typename AnyDerivedType>
    void operator=(AnyDerivedType&& ptr)
    {
        /* IF THIS FUNCTION IS ALWAYS CALLED FIND OUT IF IT'S R-VALUE OR L-VALUE AND CALL APPROPRIATE FUNCTION */
        if constexpr (std::is_rvalue_reference_v<std::forward<AnyDerivedType>(ptr)>)
            move(std::forward<AnyDerivedType>(ptr));
        else
            assign(ptr);
    }
```

Is there a clean way to do this? The difference with how std::shared_pointer does this is that instead of its operator= templated on T it templates it on std::shared_ptr, and so unlike in my example whether you provide an l-value or r-value argument it doesn't always end up calling the same function.